# Tree view with check-box react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox, treeview, multi-select

Want to achieve treeview with check boxes. 
tree view is available with

zaguiini/react-native-final-tree-view

but no checkboxes .need with selection of multiple items
Similar to below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you got solution?